# How to retrieve numerical data from BLOB column in WordPress database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, blob

I have gone through to many discussions on BLOB but most of them are related to retrieving images from BLOB column but my requirement is to retrieve single data out of several binaries stored in the BLOB column.

```
<?php $blobdata = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM slips WHERE status = 'awaiting' " );

       foreach ( $blobdata as $bd ){
           $view = $bd->bet_options_ids; echo $view; 
        }
         endforeach;
        ?>
```

The above code prints as: a:1:{i:5;s:4:"1.45";}

Here I want to store the value of i:5 (i = 5) in variable say **$store_i = $bd->bet_options_ids;**

I have no idea how can I get that individual data to store in variable or even just print out individually.

Anyone's suggestions will be really helpful.

Comment: just unserialize it

Comment: @Aki Guide me please

Comment: check my code bro it mist be correct

Comment: does it work for you?

Comment: paste your code here you will get the idea what actually happening... https://www.unserialize.com/

Comment: @Aki okay this is the dump code:  array(1) { [5]=> string(4) "5.50" }.. I need to save the value of [5] i.e 5 in the variable. Don't know if that is viable option.

Answer (score 0):

```
$blobdata = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM slips WHERE status = 'awaiting' " );

foreach ( $blobdata as $bd ){
 $view = $bd->bet_options_ids; //getting serialize data 
 $view = unserialize($view); // doing unserialize
 if(array_key_exists(5,$view)){ //checking array key is 5 or not
    $value = 5; //taking the value of 5 key element
  }
 }
echo $value
```

Comment: You are almost correct bro BUT here i=5 value is variable so it should be based on the variable key value of 'i'.

Comment: now check it, what i understand is you need $value as a 5.

Comment: No bro.. I need the  variable value of 'i' (in the example it's give as i=5) as you can see the complete print:  a:1:{i:5;s:4:"1.45";}

Comment: i is not a variable while doing the serialize it is auto setting the i as determination